# Apache, DocumentRoot effect

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

A question regarding the DocumentRoot directive as found in Apache's `sites-available` folder, file `000-default.conf` has:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

My layout of the `/var/www` folder is:

```
/var/www/owncloud  
/var/www/html
```

I'm having trouble reaching the 'my-public-IP-address'`/owncloud` subpage, and I think that's because of the defined default `DocumentRoot`. If I take away the `/html` in the `DocumentRoot` definition, I can reach the `/owncloud` subpage but I'm left with an ugly html-explorer type browser screen when I just call on my IP.

How can I fix this? Is this even normal behaviour ? Can one step outside the `DocumentRoot` or should I define another one?

Thanx in advance for your answers !

Comment: The problem is when just calling my IP I expect the apache landing page, and it does when I leave DocumentRoot alone. But it seems that way I can't reach IP/owncloud. I was hoping there was a way around this, but it seems to be I have to make a choice. Thanx for the editing ! how did you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply hide the "unsecure" automatic directory listing you can do two things:

One would be to simply put a blank `index.html` file in the root directory (/var/www/) and when your IP is entered, it will simply display a blank white page.

Another option you can do would be in your site configuration file inside the `<VirtualHost>` tag add `Options -Indexes` and this will not show any directories for this folder and all subfolders. These folders will still be accessible but whenever a root is displayed (any file path that ends in a `/`), it will not show the directory listings.

Comment: Oh two great solutions, I will certainly give that a go. Also, I might have found a third solution. Seems I can step outside the DocumentRoot using an Alias directive, but I need to go through some docs to be sure. Anyways, thanx for your solutions !